# Keras: "TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead."

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train an LSTM model in Keras, and am coming up with above error. The following reproduces the error:

```
from keras.layers import  LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1000,1000)))
```

I'm using Python 3.4, Keras 2.0.4 with TensorFlow backend, version 0.12.1

Here's the traceback:

```
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1000,1000)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 433, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 243, in __call__
    return super(Recurrent, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 558, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 1012, in build
    constraint=self.bias_constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 391, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 1004, in bias_initializer
    self.bias_initializer((self.units * 2,), *args, **kwargs),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1681, in concatenate
    return tf.concat([to_dense(x) for x in tensors], axis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1075, in concat
    dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 669, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 367, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 302, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

I've seen a few people report the same issue, e.g. [Tensorflow Slim: TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813665/tensorflow-slim-typeerror-expected-int32-got-list-containing-tensors-of-type). It seems there to be a problem with the `concat` function needing to be switched around, but here it is already in the right form.

Any idea what the cause of this is?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried lower numbers? Try (3,2) just to check....

Comment: Maybe you have a bleeding edge version of TensorFlow. I would try to update TensorFlow first.

Comment: Ah yes, updating TensorFlow to 1.1.0 did the trick. For some reason I had an old version and hadn't realised even though I installed it today. Thanks!