# TypeError on changing keras backend from theano to tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition, keras

I am trying to use tensorflow backend for https://github.com/baidu-research/ba-dls-deepspeech/ . The compile_gru_model function present in model.py gives a TypeError on changing the backend.

```
# Main acoustic input
acoustic_input = Input(shape=(None, input_dim), name='acoustic_input')

# Setup the network
conv_1d = Convolution1D(nodes, conv_context, name='conv1d',
                        border_mode=conv_border_mode,
                        subsample_length=conv_stride, init=initialization,
                        activation='relu')(acoustic_input)
if batch_norm:
    output = BatchNormalization(name='bn_conv_1d', mode=2)(conv_1d)
else:
    output = conv_1d

for r in range(recur_layers):
    output = GRU(nodes, activation='relu',
                 name='rnn_{}'.format(r + 1), init=initialization,
                 return_sequences=True)(output)
    if batch_norm:
        bn_layer = BatchNormalization(name='bn_rnn_{}'.format(r + 1),
                                      mode=2)
        output = bn_layer(output)
```

On running the GRU layer, it gives error:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got <tf.Variable 'rnn_1_W_z_1:0' shape=(1024, 1024) dtype=float32_ref> of type 'Variable' instead.
```

Even on casting the input to int32 using K.cast(), the error persists. This code worked on theano backend.

Tensorflow version: 1.1.0

 Keras version: 1.1.2

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813665/tensorflow-slim-typeerror-expected-int32-got-list-containing-tensors-of-type, caused by API change in Tensorflow. Requires downgrade of tensorflow or upgrade of Keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the issue got resolved by upgrading to keras 2.0.4.